# output panel won't update inside dataScroller

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datascroller

I have a simple example (more or less from prime faces demo site) where a selectCheckboxMenu and an outputPanel is nested inside a dataScroller (see code snippet below). When a city is selected from selectCheckboxMenu then the outputPanel shoud display it. Hower this does not work. As far as I can see, everything is executed correctly, so I have no idea why it is not working.

Any help here?

p.s. when it is not nested inside dataScroller then everything works just fine.

```
    <h:form id="vehiclesForm">
        <p:log id="log" />

        <p:dataScroller id="vehicles" value="#{vehicleTableBean.vehicles}" var="vehicle" chunkSize="10" mode="inline" scrollHeight="700">

            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{checkboxView.selectedCities}" label="Cities"
                                      filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{checkboxView.cities}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            <p:commandLink id="submit" value="Submit" update="@(.cities)"/>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:outputPanel style="width:250px;padding-left:5px;margin-top:10px">
                <p:dataList styleClass="cities" value="#{checkboxView.selectedCities}" var="city" emptyMessage="No cities selected">
                    #{city}
                </p:dataList>
            </p:outputPanel>

        </p:dataScroller>

    </h:form>
```

One interesting point, I have found out meanwhile:

when there is only one item in the dataScroller, then there are no problems, everything works like a charm.

Comment: The dataScroller is full of bugs and does not like to do teamwork. It does its own rendering of the components inside and messes up with the IDs required for the primefaces client-side code to work.